# Absolute beginner looking for solution

Tags: python

I would like to add the line which will calculate how many kg's you can put on weight to still be in "optimal BMI".
Can someone help me ?

```
name = input('Enter your name: ')
height = int(input('Your height?(in cm) '))
weight = int(input('Your weight?(in kg) '))

bmi = float(round(weight/(height/100)/(height/100),1))

#current_weight = float(round(bmi*(height/100)*(height/100),1))

#max_weight to keep bmi < 24.9  

print('\n''\n''Hey',name,'\n''Your Body Mass Index (BMI) is:',bmi)
if bmi < 18.5:
    print(name,'you are underweight!')
if 18.5 < bmi < 24.9:
    print(name,'your weight is OK !')
if 24.9 < bmi < 29.9:
    print(name,'you are overweight!')
if bmi > 29.9:
    print(name,'you are obese!')

#print('you can put on another',x,'kilograms, don't worry!')
```

Comment: This has more to do with understanding the BMI formula than programming. How would you calculate this value manually?

Comment: @Chris That's exactly what I was afraid of. Lack of mathematics knowledge may be my problem. BMI formula is pretty simple: BMI = weight/(height^2). The question is how much weight can change (as height is pretty much constant) to be still in 18.5 - 24.9 BMI bracket.

Comment: You've already figured out one important thing: "to _still_ be in the 18.5 to 24.9 BMI bracket". So this only applies if the person is _in_ that bracket. (You may want to use it for underweight users too.) Make sure to put your "can still put on another" message in the right place. Set BMI to your maximum acceptable value, plug in the user's height, and solve for weight.

Comment: @Chris Big thanks, got it working !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple, and is pretty much related to your understanding of the BMI's formula. The code that suits your requirements would be the following:

```
maxweight = (height**2/10000)*24.9
dif = round(abs(maxweight-weight),2)
print(name+", you have",dif,"kilograms to go until you reach the maximum normal weight")
```

This works for both underweight and overweight values, always returning a positive value using the function `abs()`.

Alternatively, you can use a function, which handles both cases better:

```
def getDifferenceString(name,weight,height):
 maxweight = (height ** 2 / 10000) * 24.9
 if maxweight<weight:
  return "You should go to the gym, "+name+", because you are "+str(round(abs(maxweight-weight),2))+" over the maximum normal weight"
 else:
  return "No worry, "+name+", you can put on " + str(round(abs(maxweight - weight), 2)) + " more kilos"

print(getDifferenceString(name,weight,height))
```

---

#### Explanation:

- `maxweight` represents the maximum normal weight directly out of BMI formula
- `dif` is the absolute value of the difference between the `weight` of the person and `maxweight`, rounded at 2 decimal places

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great ! I've managed to figure it out by myself. I've used the same logic but float(round... gave me some troubles. round(abs) is something new for me.

Anyway, thanks for both replies, you really got me in to right thinking.

Comment: @ffs_remi Glad I could help!